# Adding upper / lower limits and changing x-axes value format in Dash Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, scatter-plot, plotly-python

I’ve been working on a mini project using Dash Plotly to visualize some factory data I found online and I have a couple of questions that I could not find answers to.

1. How to change the format of x-axes values ? My values are in the thousands and Plotly defaults it to 20k, 22.5k, 25k etc. I actually want it as 20000, 22500, 25000.
2. While I am able to plot x and y values from the data frame easily, my data has upper and lower limits (same scale as y values) to determine pass fail criteria. These limits are in separate columns in the data frame. How do I plot these limits for every corresponding x value ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1 - How to format axis labels

From the official documentation:

https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#using-tickformat-attribute

> **Using Tickformat Attribute**
>
> For more formatting types, see: https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat = '%')
```

### Question 2

I would recommend to read out the upper and lower limits from the dataframe directly and then using the *range* property in plotly:

https://plotly.com/python/axes/#setting-the-range-of-axes-manually

```
fig.update_xaxes(range=[1.5, 4.5])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[3, 9])
```

Comment: Thank you @Stephan. I did look up the Plotly documentation but it didn’t really give me the correct format I am looking for. Examples talk about % or e format. I am looking for having the values in the same format as that in the dataframe. Plotly defaults thousands to ‘k’, how can I avoid doing that ?   For the second part, I will give it a try and update this thread.

Comment: All the d3 formatting strings are supported: http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e

I think plotly defaults to "s", so you could try with an empty string "". Or alternatively ".f"